# LDAP, Anonymous auth

Tags: openldap

I am new-ish to LDAP, and I am studying now the ACLs ( OlcAccess )

So, on the OpenLDAP Official documentation, I found this example:

access to attrs=userPassword by self =xw by anonymous auth by * none

I was wondering what effect the line "by anonymous auth" has. I really can't grasp an anonymous user trying to authenticate, because if so, they wouldn't be anonymous any more, I guess.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anonymous authentication in context of LDAP means that the client may authenticate to the server by specifying a zero length username (the bind DN) and a zero length password (which is uaually mapped to the userPassword attribute of a user DN entry). See https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Simple%20Authentication. So technically, you could browse an entire directory of a LDAP server anonymously by 'authenticating' with a null username/password.

Comment: thanks. How "anonymous auth" is different from "anonymous" in a who clause then ? .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`by anonymous auth` means that if you haven't authenticated yet (you are still `anonymous`) the only access you get is the `auth` privilege, meaning you may attempt to authenticate. So unauthenticated users may not search, read, or modify the `userPassword` attribute, but when they try to authenticate, the value stored there can be checked.

If you don't allow at least `auth` access to `userPassword` by `anonymous`, then authenticating with a DN and password won't be possible, because you won't be allowed to test the authentication password against the stored one.

I think the answer to the last sentence of your question is that you are anonymous until **after** you have authenticated successfully.

Comment: Thanks rtandy. But then, why not to put "by users" rather than "by anonymous auth" ?

Comment: `by users` doesn't include `anonymous`. Writing `to userPassword by users auth` would never match anything: if you're in `users` then you're already authenticated and you don't need `auth` access.

Comment: thanks rtandy. I meant to say: Why not just write "by users" instead of "anonymous auth"   , but I didn't mean "by users auth"

Comment: I might not be understanding the question, because `by users` and `by anonymous auth` are totally different. For one thing, with `by users` you haven't written an access level so you aren't granting anything (the `slapd.access(5)` man page says `<access>` is `+0` if unspecified), while `by anonymous auth` is granting the `auth` privilege to `anonymous`. Maybe pop into #openldap on Freenode if you want to discuss this in more detail.

Comment: I just don't get it, but thank you so much for trying. :)